# Is there a way to keep some members of a struct unmodifiable?

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct :

```
struct ABC
{
   int size;
   int arr[15];
};
```

I know I cannot make 'int size' as 'const int size' so how can I keep the size member from being modified accidently/intentionally.Is there a way around in C?

Thanks.

Comment: It's a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368028/how-to-make-struct-members-private

Comment: @littleadv: This is not the same question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be const:

```
struct ABC
{
   const int size;
   int arr[15];
};

int main() {
    struct ABC a = {3, {1,2,3} };   // ok
    a.size = 42;    // error
}
```

Comment: This will not prevent intentional modification though pointer manipulation.  Just as a note for the OP.

Comment: @Neil-isn't this(struct var initialization) a feature of C99?

Comment: @ryan Sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking about - you've always been able to initialise structs. and C99 *is* what C is today - it's not some weird offshoot.

Comment: @ryanlancer: You're probably thinking of designated initializers, which were added in C99.  That isn't this.